# Unable to Install NVIDIA drivers for RTX 2080

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics

I'm trying to configure my RTX 2080 to use with Ubuntu 18.04 and I've tried to install the latest driver through these commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

```
~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E87sv00003842sd00002182bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

If I check in Additional Drivers `Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-410(open source)` is selected under "NVIDIA Corporation: Unknown". Note that before installing this driver I got the "No additional drivers available" message.

When I run `~$ sudo lshw -c video` to check if the driver was correctly installed I get this:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       deion: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

There is no information about the driver in "configuration".

Also when I try to open NVIDIA X Server Settings it loads for some seconds, disappear and nothing happens.

I'm currently stuck at 640 x 480 (4:3).

Thanks!

Comment: Try with Secure Boot disabled at UEFI.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It worked, thanks! All those issues are now gone! Do you mind posting the answer so I can accept it as the best answer?

Comment: Not sure if it's the best answer though. Some people would suggest keeping the secure boot and signing the Nvidia drivers instead (the reason you were having problem is because Secure Boot was preventing the Nvidia unsigned drivers to load, hence the "unclaimed" status for the graphics card).

Comment: I will learn more about signing drivers, but I will be using the first solution until then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In UEFI systems the Secure Boot feature prevents loading unsigned drivers.

The Nvidia proprietary drivers are unsigned therefore Secure Boot wouldn't allow them resulting in an "unclaimed" status. The installation of Nvidia drivers also blacklisted the open-source `nouveau` that would have otherwise "claimed" the graphics card.

Solutions are (1) disable Secure Boot at UEFI -or- (2) sign the Nvidia drivers.